# Palindrome program not giving correct results

Tags: java

My palindrome program only gives a true if the word is one letter. All other options give false, even when I use a proper palindrome. I don't know if the issue is my use of s.length or what. The code is below:

```
package palindrome;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Palindrome {

    static String pal; //entered string
    static int n = 0; //used to control substrings
    static boolean isPalindrome; //boolean to control if the string is a palindrome

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//create scanner
        System.out.print("Enter a string: ");
        pal = scan.nextLine(); //turn input into string
        palindrome(pal); //use palindrome method
        if (isPalindrome == true) { // if it is palindrome, use this message
            System.out.println("The string is a palindrome");
        } else { //if not, use this method
            System.out.println("The string is not a palindrome");
        }
    }

    static boolean palindrome(String s) {
        int m = s.length() - 1; //use this int to create the upper limit for string
        switch (s.length()) {
            case 1: // if the word is one letters, it is a palindrome
                isPalindrome = true;
                break;
            case 2: //if the word is two letters, compare the two letters to determine if it is a palindrome
                if (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1)) {
                    isPalindrome = true;
                } else {
                    isPalindrome = false;
                }
                break;
            default: //recursively determine if it is a palindrome
                if (s.charAt(n) == s.charAt(m)) {
                    palindrome(s.substring(n++, m));
                } else {
                    isPalindrome = false;
                }
                break;
        }
        return isPalindrome; //return the boolean
    }
}
```

edit: I edited it and went through the debugger. For some weird reason it goes through and gets isPalindrome to be true, but then goes back to the loop again, and I don't really understand why.

```
public class Palindrome {

static String pal; //entered string
static int n = 0; //used to control substrings
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);//create scanner
    System.out.print("Enter a string: "); 
    pal = scan.nextLine(); //turn input into string
    palindrome(pal); //use palindrome method
    if(palindrome(pal) == true) // if it is palindrome, use this 
    message
    {
        System.out.println("The string is a palindrome");
    }
    else //if not, use this method
    { 
        System.out.println("The string is not a palindrome");
    }
}
static boolean palindrome(String s)
{
    boolean isPalindrome = false;
    switch (s.length()) {
        case 1: // if the word is one letters, it is a palindrome
            isPalindrome = true; 
            break;
        case 2:
            if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(1))
            {
                isPalindrome = true; break;
            }
            else isPalindrome = false; break;
        default: //recursively determine if it is a palindrome

            if (s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
             {palindrome(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));}
            else
            {isPalindrome = false;}
            break;
    }
    return isPalindrome; //return the boolean
}}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Get rid of the global `isPalindrome` flag. `palindrome` is both returning a value *and* setting a global flag. It should only return a value. Do this and you may discover the problem in the process.

Comment: return s.equals(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your *recursive* implementation is that it uses a static variable. This is always a bad sign that needs to be fixed: remove `isPalindrome` static variable, and replace it with a local variable by the same name.

Now that this is done change the last case to return the value returned by `palindrome(s.substring(n+1, m))` to fix the problem.

**Note:** You can optimize your code structure to have only two cases - a base case and a recursive case, rather than three (one letter, two letters, more than two letters). This will also fix a crash would result from passing an empty string, because your current code processes it in the `default` case.

Base case should return `true` for strings of length less than two. Recursive case should continue operating the way that your `default` case does; note that it would work for two letters as well, because an empty "middle" string is processed correctly as a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

Like @dasblinkenlight already mentioned, the basic problem is with your use of static fields in a recuresive method. Each of your call to palindrome -method is using same field variables. The field values are changing on every recursive call. If you want to use recursion, your should send all state information for method in parameters.

As a whole, this is a good case to check out how to design your algorithm. Recursive algorithms can be very powerful, but in many cases the same thing can be implemented easier and more robust way.

Here is an example of shorter version to do the same trick:

```
public static boolean isPalindrome(String s) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = s.length() - 1;

    while (i <= j) {
        if (s.charAt(i++) != s.charAt(j--))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This example makes uses empty string as a palindrome. Also good to mention, that in production code there should also be a null check for param.